# View Inflation and custom views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a custom view in my app that I draw using the `onDraw()` function in the View. Also it needs some data from the ACtivity to draw the graphic. So instead of using the standard `setContentView(R.layout.myview)` I am using the following -

```
MyView mv = new MyView(this, userData);
setContentView(mv);
```

This seemed to work until I added a `textview` above the customview. Then I realized that the above code does not show the textview at all. Also the `onFinishInflate()` is never called. Do I have to inflate the layout myself in this case? If so do I have to call the `onDraw()` function myself too?

Thanks,
- P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should have here is a layout that contains the `TextView` and your `MyView` and then inside your activity, find your custom view and pass in your user data. Your `MyView` can then use this during its `onDraw()`. Perhaps something like this:

`res/layout/main.xml`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="veritcal">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World" />
    <my.package.MyView
        android:id="@+id/myview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`src/my/package/MyView.java`:

```
public class MyView extends View {
    UserData mUserData = null;
    public void setUserData(userData) {
        mUserData = userData;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        performCustomDrawingWithUserData(mUserData);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

`src/my/package/MyActivity.java`:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // pass the user data into myview here.
        MyView myView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myview);
        myView.setUserData(userData);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

> `onFinishInflate ()`
>
> Finalize inflating a view **from
>   XML**. This is called as the last
>   phase of inflation, after all child
>   views have been added.

When you create your view by code (`new ...`) you are not inflating it... on the other hand, if you declare it in the XML or you use something like `getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_view,null,null);` then you are inflating it (and `onFinishInflate`) will be called.

It does not matter how you are doing it, `onDraw` method will always be called; so you don't have to invoke it manually.

By the way... it's always a good idea to keep your custom view on the XML, even if it needs data. So you have at least two options:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_layout);
YourCustom custom = (YourCustom)findViewById(R.id.custom);
custom.setUserData(userData);
```

or... you can fetch that data from the custom view (not recommended):

```
// inside your custom view...
UserData userData = Someclass.getUserData(getContext());
// etc... so that you don't have to pass it from the activity
```