# How can I create round volume control in android?

Tags: android, controls, volume, rounding

I need to create round volume control, which should looks like this sample:

[image: sample]
http://dmonzon.com/2011/04/16/free-tabletphone-user-interface-professional-set-v-7/

Are there any tutorials or ideas which way is better for things like this?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I do know that you should definitely make sure that it goes up to 11.

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use a custom view:

- Create a custom view
- Draw the button in the custom view
- Use onTouchEvent
- In on MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE call
  invalidate();
- In onDraw calulate the angle between
  your finger and the centre of the
  button using atan2() function
- Then use canvas.rotate to make the
  button follow the finger.

Some examples which may help:
Simple custom view and how to set the initial data (e.g. volume): [View Inflation and custom views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6308106/view-inflation-and-custom-views)

Rotate bitmap: [Android: How to rotate a moving animated sprite based on the coordinates of its destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6003823/android-how-to-rotate-a-moving-animated-sprite-based-on-the-coordinates-of-its/6004218#6004218)

onTouchEvent and invalidate: [Make certain area of bitmap transparent on touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368774/make-certain-area-of-bitmap-transparent-on-touch/5439357#5439357)

How will the custom view comunicate back the volume? If your activity has a public static volume variable then the custom view can set a volume by calling MyActivity.volume = (100/360)*angle, or better your activity could have a public static method setVolume(volume){...} which then can perform some code when volume changed - Within the volume button custom view call MyActivity.setVolume(volume);